Does the Object Browser in Visual Studio have any advanced search syntax?
Many search systems have an advanced search syntax with features such as quoted strings and boolean operators. Does the Object browser in Visual Studio have this?
For instance, if I wanted results having ".List" but not "System.", I might type one of the following:

".List" not "System."
".List" -"System."

But I cannot find anything about this anywhere in the Help or via Google search results.

No, the search functionality is very basic. If you'd like to see improved search functionality, you'll have to request the feature, or find an existing request and vote on it.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/suggest-a-feature?view=vs-2022
